# Modify complete MySQL table data using PHP interface

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to make an administrator interface for a MySQL table. I'm printing out the whole table data into input fields using PHP and want to save the edited changes to back to the table. My questions:

1. How can I pass them arguments again as form data using POST method?
2. How can I find out the affected rows alone and save the changes?
3. How do I check and delete selected rows?

PHPMyAdmin does a similar task. So I'm quite sure that this is a common situation that occurs while designing administrator interfaces.

**Edit:**

Here's the code that I'm using to print out the table (Note, this is just a snippet to provide an idea about what I'm trying to achieve):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['name']."'></td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['company']."'></td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['contact']."'></td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['website']."'></td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['category']."'></td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['subcategory']."'></td>
<td><input type='text' value='".$row['comments']."'></td>";
```

I am stuck with this as of now and unable to proceed.

Comment: Kindly show us some code and then we can help you further!!

Comment: There are many widgets you can use for this, such as jqGrid, datatables, jstree.

Comment: @MarcB I've just shown a snippet to provide a concise idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to know if you have any column in your table that acts as a key (primary or unique) so that I can post a special html template that will generate your form.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the form is submitted, you get the POST data, not before. You need to also provide a `<input type="submit">` and a valid PHP page to accept and process that response.
2. You can use JavaScript for that, disable all fields that weren't changed since they were initialized, then they won't be sent as POST data.
3. Simple, have `<input type="checkbox">` with the row's ID as value, and if it's checked, delete that line.

I'm not a fan of spoon feeding. I gave you a general direction, think well, and research on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, you want to replicate the functionality of a community driven project with 1000s of man-hours invested by asking a question on how to create what would seem like the equivalent of an html spreadsheat on your browser. Ok, first come my assumptions

- There aren't too many records, less than a 100
- The table column `name` is a unique identifier for each row (no duplicates)
- You are not uncomfortable sending large amounts of data on each post request
- You will handle the escaping on the server side

### thetemplatemaker.php

here we create the variables that populate the template. The idea here is to create form elements that can hold enough information for our processing script. The input fields shoud look like the following

```
<input type="text" name="c[uniqueID][colName]" value="an escaped string" />
```

I subsequently added a special checkbox that can be filtered on the server side to process only the rows that are checked, no need to process the whole table every time. You can do some extra fancy stuff with Ajax here as well. And voilà, there you go

```
<?php
// assume these are the table attributes
$sqlColNames = 'name,company,contact,website,category,subcategory,comments';
$query = 'SELECT '.$sqlColNames.' FROM mytable';
// assume $con is your database link
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$cols = explode(',',$sqlColNames);
$tRows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $tData = array();
  // assume col:name is a unique identifier for each row
  $id = 'c['.$row['name'].']';
  $tData[] = '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$id.'[process]" value="1">';
  foreach ($cols as $col) {
    $tData[] = '<input type="text" name="'.$id.'['.$col.']" value="'.htmlspecialchars($row[$col]).'">';
  }
  $tRows[] = '<td>'.implode('</td><td>',$tData).'</td>';
}
// the only template variables we need
$tRows = '<tr>'.implode('</tr><tr>',$tRows).'</tr>';
$hRow = '<tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>'.implode('</th><th>',$cols).'</th><tr>';
```

### thetemplate.php

here is a simple form-table template

```
<form method="post" action="your/processing/script.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="someKey" value="someVal" />
  <table>
    <thead><?php echo $hRow; ?></thead>
    <tbody><?php echo $tRows; ?></tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Submit Changes</button>
</form>
```

### the processing script

Ok, so now the user hits the button, and your script is called. Luckily, all the data sent

- is in `$_POST['c']`,
- every row is `$_POST['c'][$uniqueNameOrId]`,
- every value is `$_POST['c'][$uniqueNameOrId]['colName']`

you may now do the following iteration to traverse the data

```
foreach ($_POST['c'] as $id => $row) {
  // if you didn't hit the checkmark you don't get processed
  if (!isset($row['process'])) continue;
  // $row holds all the info for each column - Neat!
}
```

## this is a complex javascript

It is untested and unfinished. The ajax portion of the script is not implemented, nor is the response handler configured. Take a look at the complexity behind this question

- make the checkboxes filter only the rows to be sent to the server
- set an event handler that **listens** to changes in checkbox status, save the row index to help with the filter
- change the default behaviour of the form submit action (we don't want to send everything)
- setup a procedure to retrieve all input data from each row that is indexed
- make an ajax post request to send all the data to the server for processing
- handle the response from the server
- do some cleanup

As you can see the task at hand is very large, and this is not the only way to do it

```
(function(){
  var
    // php handler script, receives the ajax call and returns a JSON response
    url = 'http://your/handler/script.php',
    // this is a hack, I'm sure this can be done some other way'
    re_getColName = /\[([^\]]+)\]$/,
    // hold rowIndexes for fetching their contents later, this can also be done differently
    checkedRows = [],
    // the <form> DOMElement node
    form,
    // the <tbody> DOMElement node container of the rows
    tbody,
    // a convenient function to retrieve input values
    gatherRowContent,
    // a convenient function that returns all data by rows into an array
    gatherData,
    // a bunch of event handlers
    onChecked,
    // a special event handler, it captures all clicks in <tbody> but chains only checkboxes
    //  event delegation is important because there are too many checkboxes to setup
    onDelegatedClick,
    // not a page event handler, this is run once the server has completed the ajax response
    onResponseReceived,
    // capture submit and send through ajax
    onSubmit,
    // convenient window event handlers
    onLoad, onUnload;
  gatherRowContent = function (row) {
    var data = {};
    [].forEach.call(row.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]'),function(input){
      //this is very bad for performance, there must be another way
      data[re_getColName.match(input.name)[0]] = input.value;
    });
    return data;
  };
  gatherData = function () {
    var
      rowData = [],
      nodeList = tbody.childNodes;
    checkedRows.forEach(function(rowIndex){
      rowData.push(gatherRowContent(nodeList[rowIndex]));
    });
    return rowData;
  };
  onChecked = function (checkbox) {
    var idx = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    checkbox.checked ? checkedRows.push(idx) : checkedRows.splice(checkedRows.indexOf(idx),1);
  };
  onDelegatedClick = function (event) {
    var targetNode = event.target;
    if (targetNode.tagName === 'INPUT' && targetNode.type === 'checkbox') {onChecked(targetNode);}
  };
  onSubmit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = gatherData();
    // possibly make data a large json or just pass it into jquery
    // make an ajax request and pass the data to the server
    // this is for homework, I recommend using jQuery but there are many other options
  };
  onResponseReceived = function (someSignature) {
    // handle the ajax response data
    // possibly do some other global things like uncheck all checked checkboxes (say that 3 times out loud)
  };
  onLoad = function () {
    form = document.getElementById('formSpreadsheet');
    tbody = document.getElementById('spreadsheet');
    tbody.addEventListener('click',onDelegatedClick,false);
    form.addEventListener('submit',onSubmit,false);
  };
  onUnload = function () {
    tbody.removeEventListener('click',onDelegatedClick,false);
    form.removeEventListener('load',onLoad,false);
    form = tbody = null;
  };
  window.addEventListener('load',onLoad,false);
  window.addEventListener('unload',onUnload,false);
}());
```

Any questions? please ask

Comment: Quite the contrary. I think it is very simple to achieve this, but I just didn't have an idea on how to do it. My question wasn't about how to send data over POST, but how do I handle so much data over POST. And I wanted a way to reduce the data sent in the request and reducing the problem domain isn't the answer to it. The table may contain 1000s of rows, but if only one row is modified, would you modify all the rows?

Comment: Oh, very simple you say... and you only have `[php]` and `[mysql]` to achieve this... no `[jQuery]`, no `[ajax]`, hell not even any [javascript]. **Ok**, let me put this clear. The solution I posted is completely answering the 3 questions you asked. If you want to limit the amount of data sent by the client you will need to add some **behaviour** (_javascript_) to your fullblown application. Go read on javascript, ajax and jquery, and **edit your question** to reflect this so other posters can know about it. I'll try and give some pointers on what to do next, but tomorrow I guess

Comment: Thanks man, you're right. I'll try out your solution. I had added Javascript as a tag to my question, but some great person seems to have removed it ;)

Comment: then add the tags and I'll give you some pointers on what to do next ^^ (it involves javascript and hopefully jQuery)

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? I'm working on the concept but I want to know if you're still interested

Comment: I'm trying it by myself too, but haven't got it working yet. I'm sure the solution would benefit a lot of people.

Comment: OK, I'll get on it as soon as P. I'll post the script later ^^

Comment: Your script is there, as always, look at it top to bottom and review it and learn from it. **Do not copy paste it** directly into your project **without modification**. I haven't tested it so that's your job